# Перенаправление с помощью javascript

Tags: forms, php, javascript

Форма для выгрузки файла на сервер и обработка $_FILES находятся внутри основной разметки, поэтому после обработки загруженного файла невозможно установить header('location : куда-нибудь'). Не будет ли кощунством сделать перенаправление с помощью javascript : `location.href=''`?

Comment: Вы сделайте все в MVC и все вопросы сразу будут решены) http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller

Comment: Извините, но причем тут разметка к обработке $_FILES ??

Comment: обработав файл, страница не может обновиться, нельзя отправить заголовок, если прежде был сделан вывод в браузер. Да, ладно, я все равно пошел не тем путем.

Comment: Вам просто нужно разделять экшен файлы, которые будут что-то принимать, обрабатывать, изменять, и файлы для отображения контента.

Comment: У меня так: index.php генерирует правый див, левый див, и - динамически (с подключением) СРЕДНИЙ див.

Comment: А что мешает вырезать кусок куда обработчика из "основной разметки" и вставить до первой команды вывода? Если не можете, значит либо код не Ваш и Вы его не понимаете, либо код Ваш и можно лишь посоветовать без всякого сожаления его удалить.

А что касается js-перенаправления - в данном случае оно не оправдано, но вполне применимо. Только не забудьте вывести еще и ссылку на страницу-приемник - на всякий случай.

Answer (score 1):

Я пробовал `javascrit`-ом перенаправлять, но так хорошо не получилась. Она в полностью не обрабатывает функции `php`

Comment: никто и не собирался обрабатывать js функции пхп, имеется ввиду после обработки. Это все работает, вопрос был в целесообразности